# js require import .ts file instead of .js

Tags: typescript, import

I have a index.ts and a User.ts file

the index.ts file imports User:

```
import User from './User'
```

I then use tsc to transpile the ts files to js files and then I run the index file:

tsc index.ts
node index.js

Unfortunately this gives me this error:

```
(node:1672) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: C:\temp\dev\models\User.ts:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {Column, Entity, JoinColumn, ManyToOne, OneToMany, PrimaryGeneratedColumn} from "typeorm"
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

So it seems that my import statement `import User from './User'` is transpiled to `User = require('./User')` and still imports the User.ts file instead of the User.js

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript compiler won't automatically compile things that you import - if that's something you want, you're best off using something like Webpack or Parcel. To get all of the files in your project to compile and import properly, you'll have to explicitly ask `tsc` to do so.

There's two ways you can do this:

- Pass multiple arguments to `tsc` - e.g. `tsc index.ts User.ts`.
- If you have a `.tsconfig` file in the directory, you can just run `tsc` to compile all `.ts` files. Note that if you have a `files` list in your `.tsconfig`, it'll just compile those files.

Comment: I have also tried with just tsc. There are .js files for all corresponding .ts files but it is still the same problem

Comment: Hm, strange - I wouldn't expect Node to resolve `require("./User")` to the TypeScript file unless it the code specifically asked for `require("./User.ts")`...

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is how you have configured you ormconfig.json
It should look like this:

```
{
...
"entities": [
// change "src/entity/*.ts to

"dist/entity/*.js"
],
...
}
```